Reverse Hazard Rate
Let $F(x)$ abd $f(x)$ be the c.d.f and p.d.f, respectively, of a random variable $x$, and assume that $\frac{F(x)}{f(x)} + x$ is strictly increasing in $x$. Therefore, if I am not wrong, this includes a larger class of distributions than distributions with reverse hazard rate. Do you think this is correct?
Moreover, is $\frac{F(x)}{f(x)} + x$ is strictly increasing in $x$ for the Pareto distribution? And for other distributions with fat tails?
Thanks!

Please reformulate your question in the correct English,
If you are asking whether $Q(x)=\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}+x$ is strictly increasing then the answer is "no" as $Q'(x)=2-\frac{F(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$ can be very well negative; try e.g. a random variable with the density $1 - \pi\cos(10\pi x)/4$, $x\in[0,1]$.

Sorry, now is properly written.

Let $Q(x)=\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}+x.$ Then $Q(x)$ is strictly increasing if and only if
$$
\frac{d}{dx}Q(x)=2-\frac{F(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}>0
$$
that us
$$
2 f(x)^2>F(x)f'(x).
$$
While this is true for e.g. Pareto distribution with cdf
$$
F(x)=1-\left(\frac{x_m}x\right)^\alpha,\quad x\ge x_m
$$
as
$$
2 f(x)^2-F(x)f'(x)
=\frac{\alpha x_m^{\alpha} \left(x_m^\alpha\left(\alpha -1\right) +x^{\alpha}  \left(1+\alpha \right)\right)}{x^{2+2\alpha}}>0,
$$
it is not true if
$$
f(x)=f_0(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\frac{\pi\cos(10\pi x)}4, & x\in[0,1]\\
0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
$f_0(x)$" />
